# storing, parsing through and executing stored member functions

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on some code and need to make something like an event handler that I can register explicit events and store them into a vector that I can loop through in my main listen() function. I'm missing something about pointers that I cant pinpoint with docs and a google search and need help figuring out why my compilers asking for a pointer to a member.

I've tried creating a typedef with a member function definition but I have the problem of it not compiling currently with a "non standard syntax, put an & to create a pointer to a member." error.

```cpp
class Obj {
private:
    typedef int (Obj::*Event) (std::vector<std::string> in);
    std::vector<Event> events;

    int exampleEvent(std::vector<std::string> input);
public:
    Obj();

    int regEvent(Event ev);
    int listen();
}
```

example event code

```cpp
int Obj::exampleEvent(std::vector<std::string> input)
{
    // heres my app logic
    return 0;  
}
```

register events in constructor

```cpp
Obj::Obj()
{
    regEvent(exampleEvent); // exampleEvent: non-standard syntax; use 
                            //'&' to create a pointer to member
}
```

listen, and add event to vector.

```cpp
int Obj::regEvent(Event ev)
{
    events.push_back(ev);
    return 0;
}

// listen for command input
int Obj::listen()
{ 
    // get input
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    vector<string> input = split(str, " ");

    // loop through events
    for (auto ev : events)
    {
    ev(input); // <-- Term does not evaluate to function taking 1 arg.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have Boost, or can use it, you may be interested in Boost Signals2.  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/signals2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Obj::Obj()
{
    regEvent(exampleEvent); // exampleEvent: non-standard syntax; use 
                            //'&' to create a pointer to member
}
```

must be

```
Obj::Obj()
{
    regEvent(&Obj::exampleEvent); 
}
```

and

```
for (auto ev : events)
{
ev(input); // <-- Term does not evaluate to function taking 1 arg.
}
```

must be

```
for (auto ev : events)
{
  (this->*ev)(input);
}
```

Comment: ah yes, thank you so much! Is there certain documents I could read to learn about why the syntax would be like that?

Comment: @NelsonMcCullough in C++ tutorial / reference manual, or just read the warning produced by the compiler :-) (g++ says : `error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘ev (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* ev) (...)’`)

Comment: and the same for the constructor, g++ says `error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&Obj::exampleEvent’ [-fpermissive]` about `regEvent(&exampleEvent);` .... supposing you use g++ ;-)

Comment: I wish it was that in depth in VS, I used to use g++ and recently switched to visual studio to try it out, used to use sublime and I already miss it!

Answer (score 1):

Exxpected syntax is:

```
regEvent(&Obj::exampleEvent);
```

Comment: Ah yeah! makes sense. Do you know how would I solve the other issue within listen() function?